# How to customize migs payment gateway page?

Tags: payment-gateway

I want to change the logo, and footer (years), and alignment of the "pay" button, anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On using of hosted payment solution it is not allowed.

There are though many different third party integrations of MIGs, i.e. [Wordpress plugins](https://codecanyon.net/item/migs-custom-payment-for-wordpress/12019942), which make use of direct payment - there can be used merchant custom data to adjust look and feel of the payment page.

More info under https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickAdditionalFunctionality/supplementaryData.html

Comment: do you know any direct payment module in magento?